# Is there a way to set a limit to a dropdown height? Or even set a limit on the items shown in a dropdown?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set a height limit to a spinner with a dropdown and an autocompletetextview with a dropdown but I'm running into problems. The only option I see to limit dropdown height is "dropDownHeight" in the AutoCompleteTextView xml. That only lets me set an explicit dropDown height, which is not useful because I need a dropDown height that is relative the amount of items inside it(up to a height limit) The spinner does not even have such an option. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting an explicit value, as the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView#attr_android:dropDownHeight) says:

> Specifies the basic height of the dropdown. Its value may be a dimension (such as "12dip") for a constant height, fill_parent or match_parent to fill the height of the screen, or wrap_content to match the height of the content of the drop down.

So the `dropDownHeight` could meet your requriments.

Comment: It needs to be both relative to the items in the dropdown and it needs to have a height limit. All of the options so far only do one of those things, not both.